# ASP.NET ListView - How to set EmptyDataTemplate programmatically?

Tags: asp.net, listview

I have a class MyListView, it inherits from ASP.NET ListView. I would like to implement a default behaviour - if a programmer doesn't specify EmptyDataTemplate in aspx code, the MyListView will use a predefined default template (class MyEmptyDataTemplate).

What I have tried is this:

```
public class MyListView : ListView
{
    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        if (EmptyDataTemplate == null)
            EmptyItemTemplate = new MyEmptyDataTemplate();

        base.CreateChildControls();                         
    }
}
```

The MyEmptyDataTemplate implements ITemplate interface. The problem is, that InstantiateIn() method of the MyEmptyDataTemplate is never called, and my default template never appears in case there are no records in datasource. Apparently I wrong understand the ListView component lifecycle and template should be set somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do this on the Init event:

```
public class MyListView : ListView
{
    public MyListView()
    {
       this.Init += (o, e) =>
            { 
                if (EmptyDataTemplate == null)
                     EmptyDataTemplate = new MyEmptyDataTemplate();
            };
    }
}
```

**edit**
After checking this again I realized that `EmptyDataTemplate` was checked if emtpy, but the template which has been assigned is `EmptyItemTemplate`. However both methods are good to instantiate the templates..

Comment: I'm sorry, this is not working, InstantiateIn() is not called.

Comment: is MyEmptyDataTemplate a server control or an user control?

Comment: I declared it as private inner class of MyListView.

Comment: funny.. see the condition again what is assigned after

Comment: Ahh, I can see it now... My stupid copy/paste mistake...Thank you very much!